# Using media 9 package with adobe acrobat

Tags: beamer, media9, movie15, swf

I am using the `media9` package to embed a `.mp4` video in my beamer presentation. I am using the following lines:

```
\includemedia[
addresource=animate.mp4,
activate=pageopen,
width=250pt,height=250pt,
flashvars={
    source=animate.mp4,
    &loop=true % loop video
    &scaleMode=letterbox % preserve aspect ratio while scaling the video
}]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
```

However with this when I open the `.pdf` it says on the video page that:

> We are unable to connect to the content you have requested

If I use `VPlayer.swf` then it says:

> Unable to play animate.mp4

I am using  Adobe Reader 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
flashvars={
     src=animate.mp4
    &loop=true
    ...
```

Strobe uses the `src` FlashVar for setting the video source, see [Table 7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#table.7) of the documentation. Moreover, remove the comma after the file name.